# How to change where pnpm installs the global packages?

Tags: pnpm

Question is simple, I want to change where `pnpm` installs the global packages.

I have a custom Node installation on Windows and would prefer to have everything under that directory, especially as that directory is in my `PATH` but not the default one.

And to make it clearer I don't want to set the *store* dir, that's already configured and it's being created at the right place, now I would like to have the executable (`*.cmd`, `*.ps1`) and the pnpm-globals stuff in my custom dir as well.

`npm` already installs by default on the same directory `node` is located but `pnpm` forces on the default Roaming folder and setting `prefix` in `etc/npmrc` makes no change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `pnpm-prefix` config with the desired location

```
pnpm config set pnpm-prefix <dir>
```

Comment: Thanks, this should be in the docs. And maybe pnpm could use the same dir Node is available by default as npm does.

Answer (score 22):

For pnpm v6, use `global-dir` instead of `pnpm-prefix`:

```
pnpm config set global-dir <dir>
```

Although `<dir>` can be arbitrary, to keep the original directory structure, it should be `<your npm prefix>/pnpm-global`.

From [changelog](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/blob/main/packages/pnpm/CHANGELOG.md#600):

> The `pnpm-prefix` setting is removed. Use `global-dir` to specify a custom location for the globally installed packages.

Answer (score 0):

For `Windows` users, you can add `PATH` in your System Environment Variables.
Steps to follow:

1. Go to your `Edit System Environment Variables` settings.
2. Select `Path` variable from the list and Click ***Edit*** button and then add ***New***.
3. Add the `Path` below and Click ***OK*** to save changes.

   `C:\Users\<YOUR_USERNAME>\AppData\Local\pnpm`
4. Restart your terminal if it's already open.

Answer (score 0):

If you already set npm prefix, you don't need to change it for pnpm too!
What I did was

```bash
npm config set prefix <destination location>
```

for example

```bash
npm config set prefix D:\nodejs\global_modules
```

and then I tested it using

```bash
npm uninstall -g pnpm # If it's already installed
npm install -g pnpm
pnpm config get prefix
```

The pnpm prefix was already set to `<destination>`. Conveniently, the pnpm node module also got installed in the same folder.

On Windows, I would recommend using Windows Dev Drive (available as Windows insider at the time of writing this post) which will be nodejs install location and default npm prefix to that drive because I noticed `pnpm install` felt a bit faster.

Things to remember:

- Don't forget to add `<destination>` to Windows PATH or Linux .bashrc export.
- Make sure you have write permissions to `<destination>`